# Encoding URL with special characters

Tags: r, url, url-encoding

I have the following URL with a `value` (C#) containing a special
character (**#**):

```r
url <- "https://www.myurl.com/test?req=[{\"geo\":{},\"kw\":{\"keyword\":[{\"type\":\"BROAD\",\"value\":\"C#\"}]}}]"
```

Using `URLencode()` I was expecting *C#* to be converted into *C%23*
and get:

```r
"https://www.myurl.com/test?req=[%7B%22geo%22:%7B%7D,%22kw%22:%7B%22keyword%22:[%7B%22type%22:%22BROAD%22,%22value%22:%22C%23%22%7D]%7D%7D]"
#> [1] "https://www.myurl.com/test?req=[%7B%22geo%22:%7B%7D,%22kw%22:%7B%22keyword%22:[%7B%22type%22:%22BROAD%22,%22value%22:%22C%23%22%7D]%7D%7D]"
```

However, I get:

```r
URLencode(url)
#> [1] "https://www.myurl.com/test?req=[%7B%22geo%22:%7B%7D,%22kw%22:%7B%22keyword%22:[%7B%22type%22:%22BROAD%22,%22value%22:%22C#%22%7D]%7D%7D]"
```

I have tried to play with the `reserved` parameter but without success. Is there a way to encode `url` to get what I am expecting?